# MPMediaItem crash on valueForProperty

Tags: mpmediaitem, mpmediaquery

I have a big problem to get the informations of the songs from the iPod library. Following the official apple reference:

```
MPMediaQuery *query = [MPMediaQuery songsQuery]; // query is an autorelease object
NSArray *itemsFromGenericQuery = [everything items];
for (MPMediaItem *song in itemsFromGenericQuery) {
NSString *songTitle = [song valueForProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyTitle];
NSLog (@"%@", songTitle);
}
```

After some debugging I found that itemsFromGenericQuery has not nil value. The problem is that on a 3.x device with a library of about 1000 songs, spends too much memory to carry out the process and it crashes (or crashes on a single nil value). How can i fix it?

Comment: Edit: I solved the problem by using a thread which runs all that piece of code. So you just have to call: [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector: ...];